# Is the total differential smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $F$ is a smooth map form the smooth manifold $M$ to $N$, then $F$ induces a map between the tangent bundle of $M$ and $N$, which is the total differential $dF$. I think $dF$ should be smooth.

Since $F$ is smooth, there are charts $(U,f)$ and $(V,g)$ on $M$ and $U$, such that $gFf^{-1}$ is smooth. Then consider charts $(TU,df)$ and $(TV,dg)$ on $TM$ and $TN$, $dgdFdf^{-1} = dgFf^{-1}$, $RHS$ is  the differential of a smooth function on Euclidean spaces, why would it be smooth?

Comment: What is your definition of "smooth"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "smooth" means $C^\infty$, this is immediate from the definition.  A function $f$ (between open subsets of Euclidean space) is $C^k$ iff the $k$-fold differential $d(d(\dots d(df)\dots))$ (with $k$ $d$'s) exists and is continuous, and $f$ is $C^\infty$ if it is $C^k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.  If $f$ is $C^k$, then $df$ is $C^{k-1}$, since the $(k-1)$-fold differential of $df$ is just the $k$-fold differential of $f$.  So if $f$ is $C^\infty$, then so is $df$.

Comment: I am taliking about differential between smooth manifolds

Comment: But you already reduced that question to the smoothness of the differential of a smooth function between Euclidean spaces.